# Codename One .properties

Tags: properties, codenameone

I am wondering if, with codename one, you can create a "properties" file on a device, to store application settings in. If this isn't the case, what would be the optimal way to implement settings using a non-cloud solution? I am guessing an XML file that you can store with the application on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

you can use store files but using com.codename1.io.Preferences is probably better/easier to store some settings.